# Rearrange Array Result of MySQLi Query

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I have a MySQLi query that fetches data from my database in json format. Now I want to rearrange the result to form a new array using PHP.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "angular");

$out = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
$query = $conn->query($sql);

while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
    $out[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($out);
```

The result of this query is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "0": "1",
    "1": "Neovic",
    "2": "Devierte",
    "3": "Silay City",
    "memid": "1",
    "firstname": "Neovic",
    "lastname": "Devierte",
    "address": "Silay City"
  },
  {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "Julyn",
    "2": "Divinagracia",
    "3": "E.B. Magalona",
    "memid": "2",
    "firstname": "Julyn",
    "lastname": "Divinagracia",
    "address": "E.B. Magalona"
  },
  {
    "0": "3",
    "1": "Gemalyn",
    "2": "Cepe",
    "3": "Bohol",
    "memid": "3",
    "firstname": "Gemalyn",
    "lastname": "Cepe",
    "address": "Bohol"
  },
  {
    "0": "4",
    "1": "Tintin ",
    "2": "Demapanag",
    "3": "Talisy City",
    "memid": "4",
    "firstname": "Tintin ",
    "lastname": "Demapanag",
    "address": "Talisy City"
  },
  {
    "0": "5",
    "1": "Tintin ",
    "2": "Devierte",
    "3": "Silay City",
    "memid": "5",
    "firstname": "Tintin ",
    "lastname": "Devierte",
    "address": "Silay City"
  }
]
```

Now I want a result with something like this:

```
[
    firstname: {"Neovic", "Julyn", "Gemalyn", "Tintin", "Tintin"},
    lastname: {"Devierte", "Divinagracia", "Cepe", "Demapanag", "Devierte"}
]
```

Can this be achieve in PHP? any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything for this....

Comment: If you don't need other data, you also could `SELECT firstname,lastname FROM members` instead of `SELECT *`.

Comment: nurhodelta_17  a small change in whaile loop will give you your desired output. Check my answer once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1.Since you didn't needed all data so do query like this:-*

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname FROM members";
```

*2.Change while loop code like below and you are done:-*

```
while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
    $out['firstname'][] = $row['firstname'];
    $out['lastname'][] = $row['lastname'];
}
```

*So complete code need to be:-*

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "angular");

$out = array();

$sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname FROM members";
$query = $conn->query($sql);

while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
    $out['firstname'][] = $row['firstname'];
    $out['lastname'][] = $row['lastname'];
}

echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: @GYaN  din't get you what you are telling

Comment: Nothing now... All fine +1

Comment: Thank you for this @AlivetoDie

Comment: @nurhodelta_17  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

You could store your data in separate arrays :

```
<?php
$firsts = [] ;
$lasts = [] ;
while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $firsts[] = $row['firstname'] ;
    $lasts[] = $row['lastname'] ;
}
$out = ['firstname' => $firsts, 'lastname' => $lasts] ;
?>
```

Comment: No need to create two seperate array,doinf assignments to those two array inside `while` and then assign them to a final array. You can do it with one variable itself. check my answer once

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$i=0;
while ($row = $query->fetch_array())
{
    $user[$i]['first_name'] = $row['firstname'] ;
    $user[$i]['last_name'] = $row['lastname'] ;
   $i++;

 }
json_encode($user);
?>
```

Comment: No need to create two seperate array, first assign to them and then assign them to a final array. You can do it with one variable itself. check my answer once

Comment: Are you sure. Because i think i am correct (already tested). Although your answer is far away from What OP expected.